# How to merge two data.frame by "or"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have a data frame with the next columns (df1):

| Codes | Oxy | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100095 | 30% | 1 |
| 100096 | 50% | 1 |
| 100097 | 20% | 1 |
| 100095 | 40% | 2 |
| 100096 | 10% | 2 |
| 100097 | 20% | 2 |

And another one with addional data that I want to merge with (df2):

| Code1 | Code2 | Spp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100095 | 345550 | Sz |
| 104568 | 100096 | Cg |
| 983488 | 100097 | As |

This second df have additional information but not the same number of rows. As you can see the codes are similar but not always from the same column. Then, what I want to do is to merge both df but saying "Codes" = "Code1" or "Code2". If the codes are similar with one of the two column then the rest of the data on that row should be merge.

I have tried with:

```
df3<-merge(x = df1, y = df2, all.x = TRUE)
```

but it only copy all the extra data to each row without taking account the codes.
Hope I explain my self and thank you so much.

I want the spp variable add to each row that have the same code between both df, but considering one of the two codes column from the df2.

Comment: Hello, Eduardo, why do not try to repeat df2 this way: `df2 <- rbind(data.frame(Codes=df2$Code1, df2[,-1:-2]), data.frame(Codes=df2$Code2, df2[,-1:-2]))` then merge the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, iteratively joining based on equalities:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("Codes" = "Code1")) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("Codes" = "Code2")) %>%
  mutate(Spp = coalesce(Spp.x, Spp.y)) %>%
  select(-Code1, -Code2, -Spp.x, -Spp.y)
#    Codes Oxy Date Spp
# 1 100095 30%    1  Sz
# 2 100096 50%    1  Cg
# 3 100097 20%    1  As
# 4 100095 40%    2  Sz
# 5 100096 10%    2  Cg
# 6 100097 20%    2  As
```

Alternatively, we can do a single join after pivoting the data. This has the advantage that if you actually have more than 2 `Code#` fields, this will work with "1 or more", not hard-coding 2:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(df2, -Spp, values_to = "Codes") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  left_join(df1, ., by = "Codes")
#    Codes Oxy Date Spp
# 1 100095 30%    1  Sz
# 2 100096 50%    1  Cg
# 3 100097 20%    1  As
# 4 100095 40%    2  Sz
# 5 100096 10%    2  Cg
# 6 100097 20%    2  As
```

One possible gotcha with this: if there are more than one `Spp` for a particular code, then this will cause duplicate rows, resulting in more than 6 rows (given this `df1`). If that's a concern, then you may need to do something like `pivot_longer(...) %>% distinct(Codes, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% left_join(...)`, or choose another reduction method such that nothing in this new `Codes` column is duplicated.

Comment: Thank you so much. The first code worked. However, I have multiple column on both df. The code work but I've repeated the mutate() and coalesce() for each column of the df2. How can I make it shorter without calling each column?

Comment: The second code block is meant (specifically!) to address more than two `Code#` columns in `df2`. I don't know exactly what you mean with more columns in `df1`, though.

Comment: Sorry, did'nt explain my self. I mean, df2 have multiple columns that I want to pass to df1. Like, Spp, region, acs, site, ..., the first code block have the `mutate(Spp = coalesce(Spp.x, Spp.y)) %>% select(-Code1, -Code2, -Spp.x, -Spp.y)` There I added more lines with mutate() with all the other columns I want to pass from df2 to df1. However, it is neccesary to put each line or could I make shorter?.